# Response from Postman shows 200, But Android returns 403

Tags: php, android, api, android-volley, postman

I was trying to develop an android app using Volley, The api I used to communicate is working fine when I checked with `POSTMAN` and retrieves `200` .

But when I use the same API in my App its returns me `403` "Forbidden" 
`<p〉You don't have permission to access /API/checkPassOtp on this server.〈/p〉`

Please find the screenshot.
[image: ScreeShot]

I have tried multiple solution for this issue, But nothing worked for me.

Can anyone please help me.

Attaching volley code and error response

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonBody.put("otp", otp);
    Log.e("jsonBody", jsonBody.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // handle response data
        VolleyHelper.progressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("onResponse", response.toString());

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyHelper.progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("onErrorResponse", error.toString());

    }

}) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return params;
    }
};


jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
Application.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, "app");
volleyHelper.showProgressDialogWithTitle(MainActivity.this);
```

[image: Error response]

Comment: And now you expect us to give feedback on an API call you made using code you kept completely secret …? Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: what kind of authorization method are you using with Postman?

Comment: I see there are 13 headers you haven't shared, some of which are probably necessary to access the API

Comment: Question has updated with the error response and Volley code.

Comment: Content-Type", "application/json" is the header which I used in volley

Comment: are you retrieving data or send data?

Comment: I am retrieving data from server

Comment: try "Request.Method.GET" in place of "Request.Method.POST".

Comment: I already tried GET instead of POST, But no changes.

Comment: you are probably using in postman and not using in Android something that you are hidding from us. Code 403 means that the web service thinks that you have no permission to access that resource. Probably also it filters for example, by IP.

Comment: your app should be connected to your company's network (its what error says)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

> "Accept", "application/json"

in your params (use both).

I have to use x-api-key when connecting with my company's webserver, but I'm not sure if you'll need it.

Answer (score 0):

--> Use `https` instead of `http` in android , Postman seems fine with the http, but OkHttp needed https.

I was stuck for a day for this error `403 forbidden` in android , but giving 200 success in Postman .